# Spring Data ElasticSearch: returned scores are off

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have a Spring Boot project with `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE` connecting to a `elasticsearch-6.3.1` server.

I have the following scenario: for some elasticsearch query (which involves a should bool), I get different scores from when I run the query manually, using curl.

Steps I have tried: Extract query with debugger from SearchQuery before calling the repo, extract query from elasticsearch logs (using `"index.search.slowlog.threshold.fetch.debug" : "0s", "index.search.slowlog.threshold.query.debug" : "0s"`); in both cases, running the queries manually, with curl, gives a set of scores that are different from the ones given by Java api.

I mention that I couldn't find a pattern by looking at the diff between the two score sets. The scores returned by the manual query seem to be the correct ones, because I expect some of them to have the same value, which does not happen for the ones returned by the api.

If you have any ideas on what might cause this or how to continue the investigation it is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to make the api return the same scores as the manual run by wrapping the inner query with a constantScoreQuery, it seems that the TF/IDF criteria was the 'culprit'.

It is still curious, though, why the manual query behaved as ignoring TF/IDF in the first place ..